# Country triples without common point

Tags: knowledge, geography

In this puzzle, we only consider *independent* countries and we do *not*
count overseas territories as actual part of a country. 
We say that three countries form a **well-connected triple**, if each pair shares a piece of common border with strictly positive length.
Most of these well-connected triples furthermore meet at a point (at
least theoretically).

**Q**: What are the twelve well-connected triples that do not have any common point 
that is shared by all three countries?

Comment: I have corrected my question from ten to twelve triples. I had overlooked the two triples with Turkey. The "correct answer" sign goes to Christopher Fish who found the last two (and hence hardest) answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two more as yet unmentioned:

- Armenia, Iran, Turkey
- Croatia, Montenegro, Serbia

By my count this makes 12, not counting the dubious borders-in-lakes ones.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of possible triples with Russia, thanks to [Kaliningrad Oblast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaliningrad_Oblast). You may wish to exclude this, even though it is not an overseas territory, and it is an oblast (roughly, a state or province) of Russia.

- Russia, Poland, Belarus
- Russia, Poland, Ukraine
- Russia, Lithuania, Belarus
- Russia, Lithuania, Latvia

Another, possibly more "legitimate" answer not yet given is

- Tanzania, Malawi, Mozambique

Comment: I find it really odd that you want to discount ones involving the Kaliningrad Oblast, yet count one where the only sense in which there isn't a common point is that it's in the middle of a lake.

Comment: @ChristopherFish *I* don't want to discount them, I just didn't know if the OP intended to allow them.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick and easy answers:

1. France, Germany, Belgium
2. Brazil, Argentina, Bolivia
3. Congo, Tanzania, Uganda
4. Congo, Tanzania, Rwanda
5. Tanzania, Mozambique, Zambia
6. Turkey, Georgia, Azerbaijan

Comment: Kenya, Uganda, Tanzania

Comment: @dmg: But Kenya, Uganda, Tanzania share a common point somewhere in the middle of Lake Victoria...

Comment: I guess it depends on the interpretation of borders. Lakes are often considered the end of the territory of a country, rather than some line going through the lake.

Comment: But this is not the case with Lake Victoria.